# osx fuerte installation rosdep install fails

Tags: pcl, ros-fuerte, qt, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew#Install_Homebrew fail for me on step 1.7 (build higher level tools).  Specifically, the rosdep install -a fails with:

{{{
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
python_qt_binding: No definition of [ros] for OS [osx]
pcl_ros: No definition of [pcl] for OS [osx]
}}}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32929/osx-fuerte-installation-rosdep-install-fails/) by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1479 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not everything is working, please take a look at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/32934/how-do-i-update-rosdep-rules-for-osx) for how to add homebrew packages so rosdep knows about them. Also have a look [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/32706/failed-depth_image_proc-build-on-osx).

I did get pcl_ros to compile but ended up messing things up trying to get some other things working, so I offer no guarantees ... good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1